# Unity Convex Mesh Collider acting Incorrectly with Box that has Flipped Normals

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, normals, rigid-bodies, mesh-collider

I have a box with reversed normals, so you can view the inside of it from the outside. I want this box to work as a room, with collision detections and what not, and this works fine when its mesh collider is not convex. The problem is I need to make it convex because unity doesn't allow you to use non-convex mesh colliders if the object has a rigid body that is non-kinematic.

I cant have my room be kinematic due to the nature of the game.
Turning my flipped normal box convex makes it work like a box collider it seems.

I have tried adding thickness to the walls, but that didn't seem to help at all.

Are there any other work around to try?

Comment: You could always use planes.

Comment: That seems so hacky though, but maybe its the best solution. Right now I have my box filled with 6 thin box colliders, this is kinda working,  but again pretty hacky

Comment: If its a box its easier to use planes. A 'hacky' solution that is simpler and works is more preferable than fiddling the crud around with the GUI. Now, if you where using a capsule, **THEN** you would worry about this(though I wouldn't be able to help you in that case)

Comment: You can't use a single convex collider for an interior space like this. 6 plane colliders will be much more performant than a single mesh collider, convex or not.

Comment: Agreed, I guess getting hacky is what must be done. The issue that Im having is I want to be able to rotate this box, the box is filled with furniture supposed to be knocked around as you move the box. The problem is that objects can clip through the box if there is sudden movements from the box. I thought I needed to apply updates to the rigidbody so the physics gets updated at the right time, which means a nonkinematic rigidbody. With my 6 box collider solution and nonkinematic I still get clipping though. Do you think planes are a smarter solution, that will fix my issues?